# Top tag badge spacing off

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, badges

It seems the top tag badge spacing is now off on user's activities page (you have to view your own).

[image]

On other sites (and how I remember it used to being) was like this (taken from GraphicDesign.SE)

[image]

Which has the CSS that is missing on SO:

```
.badge1, .badge2, .badge3 {
    /* Other stuff */
    width: 14px; /* Missing on SO */
    height: 14px; /* Missing on SO */
}
```

This also affects badges within tags which can be viewed on other people's pages but is harder to notice. The same fix should fix it:

[image]

Isn't this spacing supposed to be here? This is true across Chrome, FF, and Edge on Windows 10.